# Are possible docker run migrate with only one specific migration_file?

Tags: mysql, docker, go, database-migration

I tried to migrate using docker at my golang app with mysql database. But i just want to do **one specific migration_file** not whole **migration_files**.

Source:
https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate

What i found:

```
docker run -v {{ migration dir }}:/migrations --network host migrate/migrate
    -path=/migrations/ -database "mysql://user:password@tcp(host:port)/database up 2
```

note: 2 mean's the **first** 2 migration_files

What i used:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/user/app/schema:/migrations --network host migrate/migrate 
    -path=/migrations/ -database "mysql://root:root@tcp(localhost:8080)/my_db" up
```

I want docker run migrate the last/newest migration_file/**specific migration_file**, but i don't know how.